# Google App Engine PHP Serving Images from Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In my app, I want users to be able to upload a picture to set for their profile. I only want them to be able to have one picture set and in storage (`Google Cloud Storage`) at a time.

When users upload the picture, it gets renamed the same thing every time. I do this so I don't have to search and delete the old file. The new file just replaces it.

The problem I'm running into is that once an image is uploaded and replaces the old image, it remains the old image even though the actual file in `Google Cloud Storage` has changed to the new image. I have verified the file has been successfully replaced by looking at the actual file in the storage browser. There is no trace of the old file.

To serve the image I am using this method: 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/images

`getImageServingUrl()` should be pulling the correct file as it is named exactly the same, but it's not. How is it still hanging on to the old image? Is the old file being cached or something?

The result of `getImageServingUrl()` is being echoed into the `src` attribute of an `img` tag.

Any insight would be appreciated! Thanks!

Update: I tried calling `deleteImageServingUrl()` before `getImageServingUrl()`, however the problem still persists.

Comment: Have you tried calling `deleteImageServingUrl` first?

Comment: I haven't. Should that be before getImageServingUrl?

Comment: Yeah, try it. If getservingURL pushes it out to the edge cache then changing the underlying file does not matter, as you seem to have noticed. When changing the file, delete and re-get the URL.

Comment: deleteImageServingUrl() should work. Please try clear your browser's cache first.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, and deleting first the original file before writing and calling deleteImageServingUrl() is not working for me. Did you solve this? (I enabled enable_cache and enable_optimistic_cache)